# Need to distinguish relationship between two entities: Account and Transaction

Tags: database, entity, relationship, h2

:)

So as it is stated in the topic - I have two entities, which are
`Account` and `Transaction` respectively. I need to find out the `Relationship` between them and the way it is gonna work in the `Java Spring` context with `Hibernate`.

Most probably I will use next fields for `Account` entity:

```
- UUID (as a unique identifier) (Primary Key)
- ownerName
- balance
```

And for `Transaction` entity:

```
- Id (Primary Key)
- transactionAmount
- transactionEmitter
- transactionReceptor
```

I thought about the relationship and `Account` could have multiple `transactions`, and `Transaction` can have atleast `two accounts` connected to it?
So it should be `ManyToMany`? So I will need to make a `Jointable` to make it work within of Spring context? And how the `Jointable` will be looking like?

Any clarification is appreciated! :)
Have a nice day everyone and thank You for help in advance!

Take care,
Paul

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the scenario states that a transaction is made between two accounts, one possible perspective is that the Transaction entity can have a foreign key referring each one of the accounts involved in the Transaction. Furthermore an Account can execute many Transaction(s) and a Transaction is performed involving two (or more, depending on the scenario) Account(s). So a Many to Many relationship could be the best description for a scenario like this.
[Here is a tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jpa-many-to-many) on how to implement a Many to Many relationship.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, Hugo :)
Also, would you stick to the Web App or console app for that solution?
And I didn't understand this part a bit, could you clarify it, please: Transaction entity can have a foreign key referring each one of the accounts involved in the Transaction

Comment: An example: We have two accounts, A and B. Transaction T is made from the A account to the B account. Suppose we have a Transaction table with fields: transactionID, transactionEmitter, and transactionReceptor. We would have a record in the Transaction table telling us that a transaction was made from the A account (foreign key to Account A - transactionEmitter) to the B account (foreign key to Account B - transactionReceptor).

Comment: Relatively to the Web Application or console application choice, I didn't really get the question, can you clarify please?

Comment: Uhh, I still didn't get the table structure of Transaction entity.
So we say that Acconut entity has, lets say 3 fields, which are: id, ownerName and balance, while Transaction entity has 3 fields: TransactionID, transactionEmitter and transactionReceptor, so both Emitter and Receptor will be a foreign keys, but what they are gonna refer to. If you could clarify me, that would be amazing :C

Comment: If we consider a transaction is made only between two accounts yes, those two foreign keys refer the table Account.

Comment: Okay, as I see it now. In the Transaction table there won't be accountId foreignkey property, but rather both Emitter and Receptor will be foreignkeys referencing to Account.Id, and then for instance while creating Transaction using POST method and passing JSON data it will be smth like
{
"transactionAmount":50,
"transactionEmitter":Account.Id_1,
"transactionReceptor":Account.Id_2
}

Comment: While making the classes according to Spring JPA one could implement the two variables in the Transaction class: transactionEmitter and transactionReceptor. Each one of these fields can be One to One with the table Account. Being, a Transaction has a transactionEmitter that identifies one and one account only, and also has a transactionReceptor that identifies one and one account only.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198597/discussion-between-hugo-alexandre-and-pavel-s).

Comment: Sure, lets move there! :)